# Pass class function as callback

Tags: php

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<?php

class item {
    public $available;
    public $name;

    public function isAvailable() {
        return $this->available;
    }
}

$items = array(new item(), new item(), new item());

function getAvailableItems() {
    return array_filter($GLOBALS['items'], $this.isAvailable);
}

$items[0]->available = false;
$items[0]->name = "x";

$items[1]->available = true;
$items[1]->name = "y";

$items[2]->available = true;
$items[2]->name = "z";

print("First available item " . reset(getAvailableItems())->name);

?>
```

But I am not sure of the correct syntax on line 15. I am using PHP 5.5.8.

I have been advised to do this:

```
return array_filter($GLOBALS['items'], array($this, 'isAvailable'));
```

But this doesn't work either:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  array_filter() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, first array member is not a valid class name or object on line <b>15</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given on line <b>27</b><br />
```

First available item

```
class item {
    public static $available;
    public $name;

    public static function isAvailable() {
        return self::$available;
    }
}

$items = array(new item(), new item(), new item());

function getAvailableItems() {
    return array_filter($GLOBALS['items'], item::isAvailable());
}

$items[0]->available = false;
$items[0]->name = "x";

$items[1]->available = true;
$items[1]->name = "y";

$items[2]->available = true;
$items[2]->name = "z";

print("First available item " . reset(getAvailableItems())->name);
```

Also gives same warnings.

The best thing I've been able to do so far is this:

```
//<?php

class item {
    public $available;
    public $name;
}

$items = array(new item(), new item(), new item());

function getAvailableItems() {
    return array_filter($GLOBALS['items'], function($item) {
        return $item->available;
    });
}

$items[0]->available = false;
$items[0]->name = "x";

$items[1]->available = true;
$items[1]->name = "y";

$items[2]->available = true;
$items[2]->name = "z";

print("First available item " . reset(getAvailableItems())->name);

//?>
```

As an anonymous function it works, but is there no way to pass a class function?

Comment: `$this` is used to refer to an instance of a class from within (non-static) methods of the class definition. Your usage in your item class is correct but the usage in function getAvailableItems is not. The line you were advised would be the correct way to call the method as a callback from within a (non-static) method of the class.

Comment: making the isAvailable function "public static function" doesn't fix the problem either.

Comment: A static version of `isAvailable()` would need to be something like 'static function isAvailable(item $item) { return $item->available; }` and could be called from *any* scope as `item::isAvailable()` or as a callback, e.g. `array_filter($array_of_items, array("item", "isAvailable"))`. [Read more on callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php). [Read more about static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Comment: You do not want to make the member `available` static as in your second example. That would make it a shared attribute across all instances of the class. I strongly recommend reading up a little more before you decide to use static properties or methods.  In my first comment, I made the distinguishment "(non-static)" because the syntax differs. But @Mudaser-ali's solution or an anonymous function are your options for calling a non-static method as a callback outside of the class in question.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) in callback php passes each value of the array in the callback function; so one of the possible solution is as follow:-

```
<?php

class item {
    public $available;
    public $name;

    public function isAvailable() {
        return $this->available;
    }
}

$items = array(new item(), new item(), new item());

function getAvailableItems() {
    return array_filter($GLOBALS['items'], 'filterItems');
}

function filterItems(item $item) {
    return $item->available;
}

$items[0]->available = false;
$items[0]->name = "x";

$items[1]->available = true;
$items[1]->name = "y";

$items[2]->available = true;
$items[2]->name = "z";

print("First available item " . reset(getAvailableItems())->name); // First available item y
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question of how can I use the function when it inside the class - you have just moved it out of the class.